# Weird nested Python lambda

Tags: python, lambda

How does this python lambda work?

```py
lambda v1: (lambda v2: v1(v2(v2)))(lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)))
```

My understanding:

1. The `lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4))` becomes the argument `v1`, and the statement becomes `lambda v2: v1(v2(v2))` with `v1` binding to the `lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4))`
2. But what is the status of `v1` in `lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4))`? An reference to itself?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this code?

Comment: This isn't calling `lambda v1: (lambda v2: v1(v2(v2)))` with `(lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)))` as an argument. The whole `(lambda v2: v1(v2(v2)))(lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)))` expression is the body of the `lambda v1:`. Evaluating this expression doesn't actually call any functions.

Comment: This does not align with the `Zen of Python` .

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: @MatthiasFripp An CTF Competition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually figure out things like this (at least simpler versions of this) by converting it into standard functions and breaking it apart:

```
f1 = lambda v1: (lambda v2: v1(v2(v2)))(lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)))
```

becomes

```
def f1(v1): 
    f2 = lambda v2: v1(v2(v2))
    f3 = lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4))
    return f2(f3)
```

becomes

```
def f1(v1): 
    def f2(v2):
        return v1(v2(v2)))
    def f3(v3):
        def f4(v4):
            return v3(v3)(v4)
        return v1(f4)
    return f2(f3)
```

So `f1` has two major parts. It defines two functions, which I've called `f2` and `f3`. Then it calls `f2` with `f3` as the argument and returns the result. The argument to `f1`, `v1`, is visible to both of these functions.

We might be able to talk abstractly about what `f2` and `f3` do, but since they'll only be called once, it might be simpler to turn them into more straightforward code that runs directly instead of being defined as a function.

The previous block can be turned into this by replacing `f2(f3)` with equivalent code:

```
def f1(v1):
    def f3(v3):
        def f4(v4):
            return v3(v3)(v4)
        return v1(f4)
    return v1(f3(f3))
```

Note that with this definition of `f3`, `r = f3(f3)` is equivalent to the following, where we replace the outer call with the internal code of `f3`:

```
# equivalent to r = f3(f3):
v3 = f3
def f4(v4):
    return v3(v3)(v4)
r = v1(f4)
```

which, with some renaming, is equivalent to

```
def f(v):
        return f3(f3)(v)
r = v1(f)
```

So anytime we see `f3(f3)`, we can replace it with `v1(f)`, with `f` defined as shown here.

If we make the same substitution for `f3(f3)` inside the `f(v)` function itself, we get

```
def f(v):
        return v1(f)(v)
r = v1(f)
```

Substituting this for `f3(f3)` in the definition of `f1` gives

```
def f1(v1):
    def f(v):
        return v1(f)(v)
    return v1(v1(f))
```

So unless I've made a mistake, `f1` is a function that accepts another function `v1` as its parameter. `v1` should be a function that accepts another function as its parameter and returns a function. Then `f1` will define this odd little function `f` and pass it to `v1`. It will take the result of that (another function) and pass it to `v1` again. Then it will return the result of that (presumably another function). The nature of that function depends on the `v1` function that you pass to `f1` when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

By investigating disassembly I found that:

```py
a = lambda v1: (lambda v2: v1(v2(v2)))(lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)))
a(lambda x1: x1)
```

runs this way:

1. It passes `lambda x1: x1` as `a`'s argument `v1`, and calls `a`, which is `lambda v1:`.
2. Then the lambda runs into `lambda v2: v1(v2(v2))`
3. It first loads function `lambda v2: v1(v2(v2))`, and packing `lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4))` as an function argument named `v2`, and calls the function `lambda v2: v1(v2(v2))`.
4. In `lambda v2: v1(v2(v2))`, it calls `v2` and passing itself as an argument, named `v3`, `v1` (aka `lambda x1: x1`) also got passed.
5. It jumps into `lambda v3: v1(lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4))`, and calls `lambda x1: x1`, which directly returns argument: `lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)`
6. Everything returns, and the value `lambda v4: v3(v3)(v4)` returned from this complicated lambda.